# sails skipper 0.5.8 timeout/freezes

Tags: node.js, sockets, sails.js, jquery-file-upload, skipper

I am using :

- sails 0.11.2
- skipper 0.5.8
- Jquery file upload

When I try to upload big files on my local machine node server, it works fine (I already changed the value of the maxBytes to an appropriate size).
But uploading the same file to the remote server,after about a minute of waiting

I receive this error :

```
 Error: Request aborted
FixedIncome-0 (err):     at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (..../node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:175:17)

FixedIncome-0 (err):     at emitNone (events.js:67:13)

FixedIncome-0 (err):     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)

FixedIncome-0 (err):     at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:280:11)

FixedIncome-0 (err):     at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (_http_server.js:293:5)

FixedIncome-0 (err):     at emitOne (events.js:82:20)

FixedIncome-0 (err):     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)

FixedIncome-0 (err):     at TCP._onclose (net.js:469:12) [Error: Request aborted]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding res.setTimeout(0) seem to solve the problem.
I am sure there is better way to fix the problem.